# Piping files with zcat to downstream command

Tags: bash, pipe, zcat

I have a program that takes two text files and returns an output.

```
$varscan normal_sample.txt tumor_sample.txt output.txt
```

Because of the immense size of the input files, I have gzipped them.
Is there a way to use zcat (or another tool) to pipe them into the program without unzipping them first?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using named pipes. But the effort to implement these pipes is equivalent to the hassle to expand your zipped files onto a temporary directory and to read these.

Comment: Process substitution and its anonymous pipes makes it easy though : `varscan <(zcat normal_sample.txt) <(zcat tumor_sample.txt) output.txt`.

Comment: @Aaron: Wow, I learned something new today. Great. You should propose this as the solution.

Comment: @ Aaron: I used your answer, but with the .gz extension for the input files, as they were gzipped. It is working, thank you!